# Set Column Colour based on top value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have some conditional formatting that looks for the highest value in ($L$68:$V$68) and makes the highest valued cell pink.

What id like to do though, is make the whole COLUMN pink.

How would this be possible via VB or conditional formatting?

I was thinking along the lines of something like

localvariable = MAX($L$68:$V$68)

And then set left(localvariable,1) = chosen colour.

Comment: sorry, sorry. I'd like to make the whole column pink, not row.

Answer (score 2):

Set a conditional format for the whole table (columns L through V) based on `= L$68 = MAX($L$68:$V$68)`. The lack of a `$` on the first column designator will make it evaluate the appropriate cell in Row 68 for each column when deciding whether to apply the format to that column.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Would L$68 = MAX($L$68:$V$68) be the formula? What would the 'applies to' range be, L:V?

Comment: @Dorbs, yes, preceded by a `=`. (I've emended my answer accordingly. Yes; apply to `L:V`.

Comment: Hmm. That's worked in the sense that it's coloured an entire column, but it's coloured the entire column where the value isn't the max. I'd have expected column U, it coloured column P.

Comment: @Dorbs, are you sure about the values? Is the number in column U prepended with a space, making it get treated like text, or something silly like that?

Comment: @Dorbs, Did you accidentally apply the formatting to a range starting with column G instead of one starting with Column L?  That would result in the 5-column shift in results.